# get part of line and append to same line

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have a file with 19k lines like these:

```
a96abbb5da0985983e113a9a7484c063  management/modules/membership/file1
d7f7dd7e3ede3e323fc0e09381f16caf  management/modules/invoices/path/file2
```

However, I would like to append the module name at the end of the line.
So the result would be:

```
a96abbb5da0985983e113a9a7484c063  management/modules/membership/file1  membership
d7f7dd7e3ede3e323fc0e09381f16caf  management/modules/invoices/path/file2  invoices
```

Is there a way to do this with for example `sed` or something similar? Preferably without an extra file, using `-i`.

The module name would always be in the path in this format: `modules/MODULENAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with sed, grab the next slash-separated field, and stick it at the end:

```
sed -r 's,modules/([^/]*)/.*,&  \1,' file
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this as inspiration by adding the -i flag and changing `modules` to `/modules/` since it was also picking up the `node_modules` path which wasn't my intention :)

Answer (score 3):

`awk` solution.

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $0"  "$3}' file
a96abbb5da0985983e113a9a7484c063  management/modules/membership/file1  membership
d7f7dd7e3ede3e323fc0e09381f16caf  management/modules/invoices/path/file2  invoices
$
```

If using gnu awk you can use the inplace feature,  rather than having to output to a second file.  e.g. `awk -i inplace -F/ '{print $0"  "$3}' file`

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with answers that are most probably correct and helpful as well, don't think I can accept two answers :) Ah well, upvoting it is the least I could do.

Comment: Beware [using gawk -i inplace like that introduces a security vulnerability](/q/749645) unless you modify `$AWKPATH` not to include `.` or make sure you run that command from within a working directory where nobody could create a file called `inplace` or `inplace.awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -i 'h; s#^.*modules/# #; s#/.*$##; H; x; s#\n##;' file
```